# Trabalhando com multiplos arrays javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala pessoa, basicamente estou recebendo 2 array por parâmetros de uma função e que ambos NÃO tem o mesmo tamanho, e estou tentando renderiza-lo em cada select específico, por exemplo:
O 1º array vem um API com as informações dos selects (valor, name...) e ele é atualizado toda vez que eu selecione um multiselect... - vou chamá-lo array-API1.

O 2º array vem uma coleção de números que são exatamente para quais selects essas informações devem ir - vou chamá-lo de array-target

Então por exemplo:

```
array-API1 = [{val: 1, name: 'Section 1'}, {val: 2, name: 'Section 2'}] 
array-API1 = [{val: 3, name: 'Section 3'}, {val: 4, name: 'Section 4'}, {val: 5, name: 'Select 5'}]    

array-target = [4, 7]
```

Eu preciso jogar os itens do array-API1 `{val: 1, name: 'Section 1'}, {val: 2, name: 'Section 2'}` no `id="select-4"`, que é o primeiro número do array-target, claro que concatenando... `$('"select-"+array-target[0]')`

e depois jogar os novos itens do array-API1 `val: 3, name: 'Section 3'}, {val: 4, name: 'Section 4'}, {val: 5, name: 'Select 5'}` no `id="select-7"` que é o segundo número do array-target...

```
function appendSelect( array-API1, array-target ) { 
    array-API1.forEach(function (item, index) {
        option = $('<option>');
        option.val(item.section);
        option.html(item.name);

        /*Aqui no appendTo que to sofrendo provavelmente... pois quero de 
        alguma forma jogar dentro do select certo, porque aqui não tenho 
        acesso ao array-target, até tenho, só que só pensei fazendo um forEach 
        dentro do outro, só que não deu certo, mas grossaramente eu queria 
        fazer um append assim, mas de forma dinâmica, desse jeito só faço pro 
        #select-4*/

        option.appendTo("'#select-'+array-target[0]"));
    });
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a mecânica. Como vc vai usar dois objetos diferentes ao mesmo tempo com o mesmo nome?

Comment: O array-API1 ele só é atualizado, por isso fiz a simulação, vendo 2 coleções diferentes, para cada array ele irá fazer um forEach e construir o <option> pra jogar no select (target)

O problema é que não consigo usar esses 2 array dentro do forEach... o array-API1 e o array-target

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender mt bem, mas será que se você remover o primeiro item da array-target, a próxima vez que vc chamar a função, o código `array-target[0]` irá pegar o "7"?

Comment: É BASICAMENTE ISSO QUE EU QUERO HAHAHA... já fiz isso, mas sempre pegando o último com o .pop() mas o problema é que é um multiselect, então se a pessoa selecionar com o shift vários selects, ele só vai retornar o primeiro ou o último...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].pop() vai retornar só o 8
Eu queria uma forma de fazer o seguinte
`array1 = [1, 2]`
`array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
`arrayFinal = [3, 4]`
(o arrayFinal receberia apenas os itens novos, que não existe no array1)

Comment: Eu pensei colocando `array-target.shift()` após o append para remover o primeiro item da array...